# DOM Element Width before Appended to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mootools

I'm sure the answer is no, but is it possible to determine the width of an element **before** it is appended to the DOM?

Once it's appended, I know I can use offsetWidth and offsetHeight.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The trick is to show the element (display:block) but also hide it (visibility:hidden) and to set it’s position to absolute so that it doesn’t affect the page flow.

The MooTools Element.Measure class does this, as Oscar mentioned.

Answer (score 14):

The Mootools Element.Measure functionality that Oscar mentioned is awesome. For those that use jQuery, here's a quick plugin that accomplishes the same thing:

```
$.fn.measure = (fn)->
  el = $(this).clone(false)
  el.css
    visibility: 'hidden'
    position:   'absolute'
  el.appendTo('body')
  result = fn.apply(el)
  el.remove()
  return result
```

You can call it like this, making sure to return the value (thanks Sam Fen for pointing that out!):

```
width = $('.my-class-name').measure( function(){ return this.width() } )
```

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago, but for anyone like me who tries to apply this, you need to *return* the value in the function you pass in. So 'width = $('.my-class-name').measure( function(){ return this.width() } )'

Comment: Great stuff. Currently using it with RequireJS - https://gist.github.com/simonsmith/5135933

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I modified the code a bit, here is a pure JS solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707458/1061438.

Comment: The idea is great, but appending to the `body` is no good enough, if you need to get actual width of the element, this doesn't work is some cases, don't forget __padding of element or its children__

Answer (score 11):

Modified the code a bit. Here is a pure JS solution:

```js
function measure(el, fn) {
    var pV = el.style.visibility, 
        pP = el.style.position;
        
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    var result = fn(el);
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    
    el.style.visibility = pV;
    el.style.position = pP;
    return result;
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<p>Hello</p><br/>";

alert(div.offsetHeight); // 0

alert(measure(div, function(el){return el.offsetHeight})); // 68
```

Answer (score 8):

What you can do with MooTools is use the Element.Measure class - meaning, you inject the element to the DOM, but keep it hidden. Now, you can measure the element without actually showing it.

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Measure

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible, at least not accurately, because styling affects these properties, and where it's put determines how it is styled and what rules affect it.

For example placing a `<p></p>` in the page would by default be the width of the body if appended as a child to it, but if you appeneded it inside for example a `<div style="width: 100px;"></div>`, then you see how that quickly changes things.

Comment: +1, with additional: the element won't actually be rendered until the current javascript execution stops.  This means you can append, get the dimensions and remove again without any visual indication that anything happened.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Get bounding client rect for an element (not exists at current DOM tree)
 * @param {!HTMLElement} el
 * @return {!Promise<!ClientRect>}
 */
function getElementRect(el) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const element = el.cloneNode(true);
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    resolve(element.getBoundingClientRect());
    element.remove();
  });
}

const div = /** @type {!HTMLElement} */ (document.createElement("div"));
div.innerHTML = "<p>Hello</p><br/>";

// Execute
(async () => {
  const rect = await getElementRect(div);
  console.log(rect.width);
})();
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/zuhairtaha/pen/QWLPjXO?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version of @kashesanders: Add the element to a div and put *that* div inside the DOM.

```
function getSizeOfNonDomElement(domElement)
{
  // setup
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  div.style.display = "block";

  div.appendChild (domElement);
  document.body.appendChild (div);

  // run
  let rect = domElement.getBoundingClientRect ();

  // cleanup
  document.body.removeChild (div);
  div.removeChild (domElement);

  return rect;
}
```

If you want to make it more secure, add a construct to check whether it already has a parent and/or is inside the DOM.